# How to catch exception on saving foreign key field value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, foreign-keys

While trying to add value into foreign key field, if same data doesn't exist in primary key field it throws exception like "An error occured while updating entries." However, i want to catch the same exception and display it in some window with message like "Value doesn't exist, please enter different value." So how can i catch this error in asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really familiar with MVC, I use WinForms, but why not try to find out the error code you get. Just put your code in a try catch block and if an exception is thrown check if the error code matches your error code and if it does use a MessageBox or something like that to show your message.

Hope this helps

Comment: Getting exception like this:{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
    [System.Data.UpdateException]: {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.The statement has been terminated."}  Can u show can i catch the above exception as you said to match error code. That will be great.

Comment: there can be a lot of different error codes. To find yours in the catch block do something like this (at least thats what I do in WinForms, don't know if you can in MVC)

catch(Exception ex)
{
 Response.write(ex.ErrorCode);
}

so you can see the error code first and then wright the if when you match the error code

Comment: Or if this doesn't work if your exception message is short try to match that like this if(ex.Message == "--some exception message--")
Do note that this is not exactly the right way to do this but it's the easiest way I can think off..